# Gesture Recognizers and Blocks

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

Can we use blocks with Gesture Recognizers?  It doesn't appear so.  For example, this does not work:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapped = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: self
     action:^(id sender) {
     }
];
```

Am I missing something, or are blocks just not supported by the UIGestureRecognizer class?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

However, this should:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapped = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:[^{
    // do stuff
} copy] action:@selector(invoke)];
```

You shouldn't probably do this, however, since it's a private method.

Comment: I think it's not recommended to follow this pattern since invoke is a private method.

Comment: @AS-CII True, nevertheless, it should work. :) OP asked "Can we" and not "Should we".

Comment: eheh fair enough. Anyway I would write that "although it is possible you shouldn't" :)

Comment: @AS-CII Added for completeness.

Comment: I think question is what works for right now vs. what will break horribly in a future version of iOS causing you to frantically hunt down every instance of the bad pattern to get a fix for all your users.

Comment: @JefferyThomas "You shouldn't probably do this" means one should not probably do this.

Comment: So, the real answer is "Just don't".  Noted.