# UITapGestureRecognizer with action in block

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have an iteration to process the `_id` value provided by JSON, and assign actions to each element in the list. My problem is that when I tap the element afterwards variable `_id` is always `nil`. Is there any way to assign the current iteration value of `_id` to each tap?

```
int i=0;
for (NSDictionary *item in json) {
    NSString *_id = [item objectForKey:@"_id"];

    //Main container
    //
    UIView *temp_container = [[UIView alloc] init];
    temp_container.frame = CGRectMake(0, i*76, 320, 75);
    temp_container.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:[^{ NSLog(@"id value: %@", _id); } copy] action:@selector(invoke)];
    tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    [temp_container addGestureRecognizer:tap];
    i++;
}
```

Here's the console output:

```
2014-08-26 18:17:32.511 appTwo[33519:60b] -[__NSArrayM invoke]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x91b6210
2014-08-26 18:17:32.515 appTwo[33519:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM invoke]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x91b6210'
```

Comment: did you add the `temp_container` to a superview?

Comment: Yes, that's how I tested the "tap" action. I just didn't want to include all the rest of the UI code.

Comment: maybe try `__block NSString *_id = [[item objectForKey:@"_id"] copy];` ?

Comment: Just did, it does not change anything.

Comment: i would suggest using `temp_container.tag` or storing the views in mutable dictionary with the `_id` and write a separate methods on `self`, also, i believe `target:[^{} copy] invoke` uses private methods

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14484941/gesture-recognizers-and-blocks